# Assembly SIMD instruction to move 64 bit register in xmm register?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86-64, intel, simd

I would like to move a 2 64 bit integer in parallel from memory to an xmm register to perform operations on them(add the same constant to each of them). I looked at multiple instructions in the intel reference manual such as movupd and movdqa but they all seem to convert the integer to a floating point.
Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: The linked-to answer seems to answer your question, but [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZXxGBc) is an example of using `movdqu`.

Comment: `movupd` and `movdq` do not convert anything.  They are typed as being for floating point numbers, but it's just a data move at the end of the day.

Comment: If you move them to different XMM registers, the two operations are probably executed (close to) parallel on different execution ports of the CPU.

Comment: Your question title asks about 64-bit *register*, but your question body asks about memory.  GP->XMM with `movq xmm0, rax`.  MMX->XMM with `movq2dq xmm0, mm0`.  Read Agner Fog's asm guide chapter on SIMD (https://agner.org/optimize/) for a table of data-movement instructions.